# How to add a value to the existing element value and return it as a new value

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts-search

This is the xml file.

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<AtcoCode> System-Start-Date= 2018-05-16T12:35:48.6929328-04:00, " ", System-End-Date = 9999-12-31, " ", 150042010003</AtcoCode>
<NaptanCode>esxatgjd</NaptanCode>
<PlateCode>
</PlateCode>
<CleardownCode>
</CleardownCode>
<CommonName>Upper Park</CommonName>
<CommonNameLang>
</CommonNameLang>
<ShortCommonName>
</ShortCommonName>
<ShortCommonNameLang>
</ShortCommonNameLang>
<Landmark>Upper Park</Landmark>
<LandmarkLang>
</LandmarkLang>
<Street>High Road</Street>
<StreetLang>
</StreetLang>
<Crossing>
</Crossing>
<CrossingLang>
</CrossingLang>
<Indicator>adj</Indicator>
<IndicatorLang>
</IndicatorLang>
<Bearing>NE</Bearing>
<NptgLocalityCode>E0046286</NptgLocalityCode>
<LocalityName>Loughton</LocalityName>
<ParentLocalityName>
</ParentLocalityName>
<GrandParentLocalityName>
</GrandParentLocalityName>
<Town>Loughton</Town>
<TownLang>
</TownLang>
<Suburb>
</Suburb>
<SuburbLang>
</SuburbLang>
<LocalityCentre>1</LocalityCentre>
<GridType>U</GridType>
<Easting>541906</Easting>
<Northing>195737</Northing>
<Co-ordinates>51.64255,0.04944</Co-ordinates>
<StopType>BCT</StopType>
<BusStopType>MKD</BusStopType>
<TimingStatus>OTH</TimingStatus>
<DefaultWaitTime>
</DefaultWaitTime>
<Notes>
</Notes>
<NotesLang>
</NotesLang>
<AdministrativeAreaCode>080</AdministrativeAreaCode>
<CreationDateTime>2006-11-06T00:00:00</CreationDateTime>
<ModificationDateTime>2010-01-16T07:58:02</ModificationDateTime>
<RevisionNumber>5</RevisionNumber>
<Modification>rev</Modification>
<Status>act</Status>
</root>
```

How to achieve this?

Question: Create the path range index for the status element and fetch all the documents that has status `del` 
after fetching all the documents, you need to create the new element called `currentreservationnumber` under `RevisionNumber` element. 
The value of the currentrevisionnumber will be +1 to the RevisionNumber.

Comment: This question is confusing. Is the XML incomplete? I don't see how multiple documents could be stored. Are you looking for an Xquery solution?

Comment: @kismert The XML is complete. The root element is <root>

Comment: It might be wise to step back a bit, and elaborate on the larger goal. We usually recommend against sequential numbers for performance reasons. Do you really need them?

Comment: Having said that, you might be looking for something like this: https://github.com/grtjn/ml-unique#uniqnext-sequential-uri

Answer (score 0):

I think the warning about sequential numbers is related to system-wide unique numbers/ids (like Oracle sequence), so not a worry in this case?

If you only ever have one RevisionNumber, and you can find it without a path index, you can maybe get by with element-value query on the RevisionNumber since it's already indexed.

Given that you get the document somehow, it could be as simple as:

```
let $doc := fn:doc ('/foo.xml')
let $rev-node := $doc/root/RevisionNumber
return xdmp:node-insert-after ($rev-node, <currentreservationnumber>{$rev-node + 1}</currentreservationnumber>)
```

though remember to consider locking if you are doing a big query/update.  And you might need to switch to node-replace if there is already a currentreservationnumber.